# Sending additional $_POST data?

Tags: php

I use a form to send some data to my welcome.php file:

```
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="txt" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But, is it possible to send other variables instead of just form element values? Let's say I want to send the number 100 to welcome.php as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably use a hidden input:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="myNumber" value="100" />
    Name: <input type="text" name="txt" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

That would send the myNumber $_POST value to welcome.php.

Modifying the action like this: `welcome.php?myNumber=100` would mean that you are sending a GET variable in addition to the POST variables inside the form.

NOTE: You could theoretically use both, but I believe that would only put the $_POST value in the $_REQUEST object. You should confirm that before relying on that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myNumber" value="100" />
```

Right?

Answer (score 1):

other then hidden fields or form element you can use `AJAX` to send other variables into the post.

where you can pass url with your new variables other than form fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode that into your action:

```
<form action="welcome.php?number=100" method="post">
```

Comment: but be aware it will be in $_GET, not $_POST

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<form action="welcome.php?number=100" method="post"/>
```

or use a hidden form input

```
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="100" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use html hidden field or store the value what you want in session or cookie varible